# Does anyone have any example using WebSocketClientProtocolHandler with binary websocket messages?

Tags: binary, websocket, netty

I'm having trouble sending a binary message over my client websocket.

We have our own message object along with to/from binary.  So I created a class that extends ByteToMessageCodec.  The call to channel.writeAndFlush(MyMessageInstance) goes into the encode, where it gets the byte[] and calls the out.writeBytes(byteArray).

When I call channel.writeAndFlush() - it enters/exits the encode, but then it never seems to make it on the wire.

Below is the channel pipeline initialization.  MessageHandler is just a SimpleInboundHAndler that takes our MessageType.  Please NOTE: I'm using the WebSocketClientProtocolHandler as the means to do the upgrade handshake, etc.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,

## Bob

```
boolean handleCloseFrames = false;
WebSocketClientHandshaker handshaker = WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(serverUri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, null);

final WebSocketClientProtocolHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketClientProtocolHandler(handshaker, handleCloseFrames);

    this.getBootstrap().handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception 
        {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast("http-codec", new HttpClientCodec());
            pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
            pipeline.addLast("ws-handler", wsHandler);
            pipeline.addLast("message-codec", new CustomMessageCodec());
            pipeline.addLast("message-handler", messageHandler);
        }
    });

    ChannelFuture future = this.getBootstrap().connect(serverUri.getHost(), serverUri.getPort());
    channel = future.sync().channel();
```

Comment: Could you share the class extending ByteToMessageCodec

Comment: `public class ThingworxMessageCodec extends ByteToMessageCodec<ThingworxMessage>
{

 Override
 protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MyMessage msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception
 {
  byte[] rawMessage = msg.getBinaryMessage();
  out.writeBytes(rawMessage);
 }

 Override
 protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception
 {
  byte[] rawMessage = in.array();
  MyMessage decodedMessage = MyMessageFactory.fromBinary(rawMessage);
  out.add(decodedMessage);
 }

}`

Comment: apologies for the lack of formatting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ByteToMessageCodec` (and `MessageToByteEncoder`) is meant to transform a custom object to `ByteBuf`.

`WebSocketClientHandshaker` will add `WebSocketFrameEncoder` into the pipeline so that you can send a `WebSocketFrame` once handshake is finished.

One thing to note is that `WebSocketFrameEncoder` encodes only `WebSocketFrame` and its subtypes.

Therefore, anything encoded by your `ByteToMessageCodec` will not be handled by `WebSocketFrameEncoder` at all, and your server will probably not understand what you sent.

To fix this problem, you have to use `MessageToMessageCodec` instead of `ByteToMessageCodec`, and encode your message to `BinaryWebSocketFrame` and decode a `BinaryWebSocketFrame` into your message.

Comment: Thanks Trustin - once I went back and looked again at what the existing handlers in the pipeline were doing, it clicked and I realized exactly what you pointed out: this is 1 message to another.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this method to the ByteToMessageCodec:

```
@Override
public boolean acceptOutboundMessage(Object msg) throws Exception {
    return msg instanceof MyMessage;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that had no effective on getting the message on the wire